# Displaying text during each loop iteration

Tags: loops

This is hopefully a reasonably simple question. But, this is my first time posting a question into a forum so it's highly possible that I won't convey my question well. If so, sorry in advance.

So I want to print some text from inside a for loop and then have Julia wait for a response during each iteration.
    However, the code that I have using (which is below) asks for an input during each iteration and displays all text once the entire loop is finished.
    A factor which might be important to note is that I have been doing all of my coding on the Juliabox website.

This is what I have been using:

```
A = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
answer = "n";
for k = 1:length(A)
    prompt = "Is this a 3? (enter y/n)";
    println(prompt)
    answer = chomp(readline())
    if answer == "y"
        #do something
    elseif answer == "n"
        #do something else
    end
end
```

This is the result I obtain:

```
STDIN> n
STDIN> n
Is this a 3? (enter y/n)
Is this a 3? (enter y/n)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this must be an artefact of the JuliaBox IDE, your code runs correctly at: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_julia_online.php

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I was worried for a second there :D